# How can i set the new position of marker with Gmaps.js?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

With GMaps.js i can add markers easy way:

```
map.addMarker({  
              lat: -12.043333,
              lng: -77.028333
              });
```

After create that marker, i want to set him a new position after some time.
For example my next code:

```
setInterval(function() {
     setNewPosition();
}, 5000);

setNewPosition(){   
   map.removeMarkers();

   map.addMarker({  
                  lat: -13.043333,
                  lng: -77.028333
                  });
}
```

But i don`t want all time a removed marker, i want only set him a new position. That is the really possible? I know in google map it solved with **google.maps.LatLng()**
 and **.setPosition()**, but how in Gmaps.js they used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is no special method to set the position.

`addMarker()` returns a native `google.maps.Marker`, so you may store this marker in a variable and call `setPosition()` later.

Answer (score 4):

addMarker() return a google.maps.Marker, so call setPosition() function with new google.maps.LatLng

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.667, 12.239);
marker.setPosition(latlng);
```